# How can I determine when YouTube video stopped for loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building Chrome extension.I need to stop the extension when the YouTube video stopped for loading and continue when the video resume playing - using *JavaScript* or *jQuery*. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the onStateChange event listener as described here :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener

Listening for states 3 and 1 are the ones I think you are after.